# How to configure a windows phone 7 to access website behind Forefront Threat Management Gateway

Tags: microsoft-forefront-2010, microsoft-ftmg-2010, windows-phone-7

As in the title.

We have a WCF service, and a Windows Phone 7 client. One of our customers wants to install the service behind a TMG server.

I know that TMG is an update to the old ISA server and I recall having to install a client on my PC to connect to a site behind the ISA server, but I cannot see anything about in any of my searches.

Is it actually possible to access the service via this gateway? If so can anyone tell me what I need to do? I'm happy to research it if I know what to look for.

EDIT:

Reading further I see that TMG an do cert based Authentication. So if a trusted cert is installed on the device, this can be connected to the user the in AD. This means that TMG will allow the packet through.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TMG *can* act in the manner you described, but it can also act a normal firewall, or as a NAT/firewall as well.

It can *also* act as a reverse proxy.

If your application sticks to standard TCP/UDP communication, TMG can publish it. If it uses HTTP, then TMG can publish it, route it, and even inspect it.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question, what I'm looking for is a way to do it. Do you have any links on how to configure the TMG please?

Comment: @preet - TMG is a complex piece of software, there's no hard and fast rule on how to do anything, because it all depends on how the network is configured (is it NATting, routing, both, etc). Generally, you'd go to the Firewall page and then go Publish Web Server (if it's HTTP/HTTPS), or Publish non-web protocol (if it's something else). From there though, it all depends. You might have a pre-defined web listener, you might need to create one, etc\

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the WCF service is hosted in IIS as a pure Web Service. In that case, publishing the Service is as [easy as publishing a website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc984433.aspx)